# How does std::enable_if work when toggling functions?

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I read about `std::enable_if` at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

It describes right and wrong way of using it.

```
/* 1st Example : WRONG */
 
struct T
{
    enum { int_t, float_t } type;
 
    template<typename Integer,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value>>
    T(Integer) : type(int_t) {}
 
    template<typename Floating,
             typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value>>
    T(Floating) : type(float_t) {} // error: treated as redefinition
};
 
/* 2nd Example : RIGHT */
 
struct T
{
    enum { int_t, float_t } type;
 
    template<typename Integer,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value, bool> = true>
    T(Integer) : type(int_t) {}
 
    template<typename Floating,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value, bool> = true>
    T(Floating) : type(float_t) {} // OK
};
```

But I couldn't understand why the second example works.

In the first example even if default argument of template is different, it is not treated as different template function. So compiler generates error of re-definition of function. This is my understaing.

But the second example also looks similar case as the first example to me.
How does the second example works?

Comment: Second snippet must use `std::enable_if`. If you notice the typo in your question, we can proceed.

Comment: In the second example the template parameters are not considered equivalent because `std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integer>::value, bool>` and `std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value, bool>` are not equivalent. So you have definitions for two distinct function templates and no error. Types/kinds of template parameters are part of the function template signature, but default template arguments are not.

Comment: @user17732522 I think that both ```std::enable_if<std::is_integral<Integer>::value, bool>``` and ```std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<Floating>::value, bool>``` result in ```bool``` type after the compiler process ```std::enable_if```.  So I consider these two types are same. Am I wrong?

Comment: @myoldgrandpa No, after substitution one of them is ill-formed and doesn't result in anything. However, that's irrelevant. The compiler has to decide whether _the templates themselves_ are equivalent. That can't possibly depend on the particular type used for `Integer`/`Floating`, so the rule is that the template parameter, if dependent, is equivalent only if, except for the naming of entities such as `Integer`/`Floating`, the type as written is the same, before substitution. `is_integral` and `is_floating_point` do not name the same entity, so the type containing them can't be equivalent.

Comment: The precise (but quite technical) rules are in https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link, specifically starting with https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over.link#6.